# Liquibase with Kubernetes, how to prevent DB being left in a locked state

Tags: kubernetes, state, liquibase, locked

Firstly, yes I have read this https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-in-kubernetes
and I also read many SO threads where people are answering "I solved the issue by using init-container"

I understand that for most people this might have fixed the issue because the reason their pods were going down was because the migration was taking too long and k8s probes killed the pods.

But what about when a new deployment is applied and the previous deployment was stuck a failed state (k8s trying again and again to launches the pods without success) ?
When this new deployment is applied it will simply whip / replace all the failing pods and if this happens while Liquibase aquired the lock the pods (and its init containers) are killed and the DB will be left in a locked state requiring manual intervention.

Unless I missed something with k8s's init-container, using them doesn't really solve the issue described above right?

Is that the only solution currently available? What other solution could be used to avoid manual intervention ?

My first thought was to add some kind of custom code (either directly in the app before the Liquibase migration happens) or in init-container that would run before liquibase init-container runs to automatically unlock the DB if for example the lock is, let's say, 5 minutes old.
Would that be acceptable or will it cause other issues i'm not thinking about ?

Comment: Actually I stubbled on this https://github.com/blagerweij/liquibase-sessionlock which seems neat but I'm not fan of adding unofficial (un tested?) libs.

Comment: maybe stupid question, but how often does happen that LB is locked? We are running init container for almost 2 years and no issue so far ;) Only one thing which you should keep in mind...don't do the backward incompatible changes in next step. So if you are on version `1` then do only forward changes in version `2` and leave the backward incompatible changes (for example drop of column/table/etc) to version `3` where they shouldn't be needed anymore. So in case something is rolled back you won't be blocked.

Comment: It actually happens quite often and there is no migration running. 
There are no error or anything that would suggest the pod is going down other than k8s whipping it out because a new deployment has been applied.
I still need to spend sometime investigating this but there still might be a chance the pod is getting remove because of the k8s probe.. but to be honest, even if init-container works, I'd prefere go the `liquibase-sessionlock` way since this is a nice and clean solution without extra code in the k8s template

Comment: Could you please also describe your K8s cluster environment that you are using - K8s version, is it bare metal installation/ cloud provider?