# liquibase initContainers for mysql in kubernates

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, liquibase

i am trying to spring init container of liquibase which has some scripts which take time
i want to execute these script before the spring ms containers come alive

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-conf           # name of ConfigMap, referenced in other files
  namespace: default
data:
  host: "mysql"            # host address of mysql server, we are using DNS of Service
  name: "espark-mysql"     # name of the database for application
  port: "3306"
```

```
# Define 'Secret' to store 'root' user Credentials
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-root-credentials # Name of the Secret
  namespace: default
data:   #to create secret $ echo -n 'valuexxxx' | base64
  username: cm9vdA== # base64 encoded 'root' username
  password: cm9vdA== # base64 encoded 'root' password
```

```
# Define a 'Service' To Expose mysql to Other Services
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql  # DNS name
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:       # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    app: mysql
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None  # We Use DNS, Thus ClusterIP is not relevant
---
# Define a 'Persistent Volume Claim'(PVC) for Mysql Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
# Configure 'Deployment' of mysql server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector: # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' selectors
        app: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.7 # image from docker-hub
          args:
            - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found" # Workaround for https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD # Setting Root Password of mysql From a 'Secret'
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials # Name of the 'Secret'
                  key: password   # 'key' inside the Secret which contains required 'value'
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE # Setting Database Name from a 'ConfigMap'
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: name
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:        # Mounting voulume obtained from Persistent Volume Claim
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'volume' from PVC
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

```
# Define 'Service' to expose backend application deployment
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-mysql-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector: # backend application pod labels should match these
    app: springboot-mysql-service-label
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
  type: LoadBalancer # use NodePort, if you are not running Kubernetes on cloud
---
# Configure 'Deployment' of backend application
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-mysql-service
  labels:
    app: springboot-mysql-service-label
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1 # Number of replicas of back-end application to be deployed
  selector:
    matchLabels: # backend application pod labels should match these
      app: springboot-mysql-service-label
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' labels
        app: springboot-mysql-service-label
        tier: backend
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: liquibase
          image: adarshkumarsingh83/springboot-liquibase-mysql
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: kubernates
            - name: DATABASE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: host
            - name: DATABASE_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: port
            - name: DATABASE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: name          
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials
                  key: password
      containers:
        - name: springboot-mysql-service
          image: adarshkumarsingh83/springboot-mysql-service # docker image of backend application
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          env: # Setting environmental Variables
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: kubernates
            - name: DATABASE_HOST # Setting Database host address from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf # name of configMap
                  key: host
            - name: DATABASE_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: port  
            - name: DATABASE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-conf
                  key: name
            - name: DATABASE_USER # Setting Database username from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials # Secret Name
                  key: username
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD # Setting Database password from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials
                  key: password
```

i am trying to execute the yaml with are in this below link

https://github.com/adarshkumarsingh83/kubernetes/tree/master/APPLICATIONS/springboot-kubernates-lisquibase-initcontainer-mysql/kuberantes

but some how only spring containers is working and liquibase init container is not executing and db and tables are not created due to that

any sort of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

with same configuration i am able to run the liquibase init container
and after that spring boot containers work fine and able to get the data which is created by liqibase init container

```
$ kubectl logs -f springboot-mysql-service-7f4f8fd9df-vgnr7  -c liquibase

                        ,--.                    ,--. ,--.                  ,--. ,--.
 ,---.   ,---.  ,--.--. `--' ,--,--,   ,---.    |  | `--'  ,---.  ,--.,--. `--' |  |-.   ,--,--.  ,---.   ,---.
(  .-'  | .-. | |  .--' ,--. |      \ | .-. |   |  | ,--. | .-. | |  ||  | ,--. | .-. ' ' ,-.  | (  .-'  | .-. :
.-'  `) | '-' ' |  |    |  | |  ||  | ' '-' '   |  | |  | ' '-' | '  ''  ' |  | | `-' | \ '-'  | .-'  `) \   --.
`----'  |  |-'  `--'    `--' `--''--' .`-  /    `--' `--'  `-|  |  `----'  `--'  `---'   `--`--' `----'   `----'
        `--'                          `---'                  `--'
2022-08-29 17:01:11.977  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.a.SpringbootLiquibaseApplication     : Starting SpringbootLiquibaseApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.16 on springboot-mysql-service-7f4f8fd9df-vgnr7 with PID 1 (/springboot-liquibase-mysql.jar started by root in /)
2022-08-29 17:01:11.980  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.a.SpringbootLiquibaseApplication     : The following 1 profile is active: "kubernates"
2022-08-29 17:01:13.120  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : hikar-pool - Starting...
2022-08-29 17:01:13.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : hikar-pool - Start completed.
2022-08-29 17:01:14.185  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2022-08-29 17:01:14.202  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.command                        : Dropping Database Objects in schema: espark-mysql.espark-mysql
2022-08-29 17:01:14.236  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Creating database history table with name: `espark-mysql`.DATABASECHANGELOG
2022-08-29 17:01:14.550  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Successfully deleted all supported object types in schema espark-mysql.espark-mysql.
2022-08-29 17:01:14.552  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
All objects dropped from root@172.17.0.4@jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/espark-mysql?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
2022-08-29 17:01:14.583  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2022-08-29 17:01:15.004  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Creating database history table with name: `espark-mysql`.DATABASECHANGELOG
2022-08-29 17:01:15.016  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading from `espark-mysql`.DATABASECHANGELOG
Running Changeset: db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::1::adarsh
2022-08-29 17:01:15.076  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : SQL in file db/changelog/changes/sql/create_schema.sql executed
2022-08-29 17:01:15.077  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::1::adarsh ran successfully in 20ms
Running Changeset: db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::2::radha
2022-08-29 17:01:15.093  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : SQL in file db/changelog/changes/sql/insert_data.sql executed
2022-08-29 17:01:15.096  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::2::radha ran successfully in 13ms
Running Changeset: db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::3::radha
2022-08-29 17:01:15.108  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : SQL in file db/changelog/changes/sql/select_data.sql executed
2022-08-29 17:01:15.109  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::3::radha ran successfully in 7ms
2022-08-29 17:01:15.120  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
2022-08-29 17:01:15.321  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.a.SpringbootLiquibaseApplication     : Started SpringbootLiquibaseApplication in 4.2 seconds (JVM running for 4.731)
2022-08-29 17:01:15.333  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : hikar-pool - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-29 17:01:15.355  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : hikar-pool - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-29 14:11:38.586  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : hikar-pool - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: I see you've posted an answer that you were able to get it to run by changing the order, which is good.  I wanted to share a couple of resources: https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-in-kubernetes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263258/liquibase-with-kubernetes-how-to-prevent-db-being-left-in-a-locked-state